# Replace multiple string with the same

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Want I want to do is replace a domain in a text string with a hyperlink.

So `domain.com`, `www.domain.com`, `http://domain.com`, `http://www.domain.com`, etc. to be replaced with `<a href="http://www.domain.com">`

Is it possible to do a replace with all these at once so I don't have to do a bunch of replace statements? Thought about first replacing each with a unique placeholder and then replacing those with a link so I don't have to worry about re-replacing a string.

Or maybe regex? I am horrible at regex so an example would be great if that's best.

Alternatively, is there a better option I've not considered?

Comment: `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` are not guaranteed to both work, or load the same page.

Comment: Note that StackExchange's markdown implementation does this, not sure if the source is available, but you could look around on meta..

Comment: Here is the auto link conversion regex that SE is using: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Converter.js#1457

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the same domain or is it anything loosely resembling an address?
If it's only domain.com you could just do a replace with the few possibilities you listed

If it's anything shaped like an address you could try a regex like

```
((http://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.([a-z]{1,2,3}))
```

and replace with

```
<a href="\1">
```

(Usually regex refer to capturing groups (whatever is inside the parenthesis) like $1 $2 $3 but in visual studio it's \1 \2 \3)

This is if you are using the GUI tool in visual studio, to do it programatically you have to access the [groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the regex match and find group 1

But it always depends on what the text you are parsing is, cause this will match any string of character that is one or more characters then a dot then a few lowercase letters

To be more specific you could change the ([a-z]{1,2,3}) to something like (com|net|org) with the possible suffixes

So you would get

```
((http://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.(com|net|org))
```

Comment: It will always be the same domain. If I am understanding you right, skip the regex concept and just do a bunch of replace statements?

Comment: If it's always the same domain you could simply do (http://)?(www\.)?domain\.com and get everything that matches that and replace it with the string you want

Comment: `[a-z]{1,2,3}` doesn't make sense, and your regex is poorly equipped to parse any link that is percentage escaped, or generic TLD/internationalized domain.